# How to detect blocks of text

Tags: java, block, lolcode

Is it possible to get block of text inbetween two markers?
I am trying to write my version of LOLCODE and i want to make if statement - then i ran into this problem.

Basic thing is, that i want to do this:

```
IS #DIR = 5
    YUP
 -if statement suceeded, execute code here-
    NOPE
 -if statement returned false, execute code here
BYE
```

Explanation: This code should check if variable #DIR is equal to five, if yes then execute code in YUP block, if not - execute code in NOPE block.

My question is : How to read this from text file and execute proper block of code using java?

Comment: Using a parser would clearly be the best avenue.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Awesome, thanks but do you have any ideas on what parser should i use - or shall i make one?

Comment: Make one, but not from scratch. There are libraries that let you start from a BNF and they take care of the rest. `antlr` is one such library, very popular.

Answer (score 3):

Try a regular expression like this:

```
searchText.matches("^\\s*IS\\s+(#\\w+)\\s*=\\s*(\\w+)\\s*")
```

This expression only evaluates The first line "IS #DIR = 5" but you can complete it is only the idea to do it ;)

Edit: Maybe this link can help you if the inner blocks of code are Java: [Dynamic code execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166135/dynamic-code-execution)

Comment: This is the stuff i know. Only thing i cant figure out is how to run a proper block of code.

Comment: I edited the answer for include the link of Dynamic code execution

Comment: Regex is useless for parsing nested structures.

Comment: Thanks, but i'll use Marko's advice on making parser :)