# Include string as code

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Is it possible in AndroidStudio to use a string as code?
For example if I load a file called `code.txt` including `Log.d("DEBUG", yourstring);` and it will be included at the Java file

```
public onClick(View v){
    String string = "It worked";
    codetxt.include();
}
```

And if it is clicked it will Log `It worked`
If this is possible please tell me!

Comment: It may very well be possible somehow, but not in any default way. Would be a huge security problem.

Comment: See this answear here [Dynamic Code Execution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166135/dynamic-code-execution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can it with reflection. But it's not simple. I used other JVM languages like `clojure` or `Jython` for similar tasks.