# Deserialize into dynamic Java types

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

My problem today is that I have this kind of JSON,
with an array of objects, each object having
two properties: `type` and `value`.

```js
[{
    "type": "Boolean",
    "value": false
}, {
    "type": "String[]",
    "value": ["one", "two", "three"]
}]
```

As you see, the `value` class depends on the `type`.
I may have a `type: MyClass`, with `value` being a complex object.

I want to be able to deserialize this array (and serialize it back
into JSON afterwards).

I started looking into the [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library, but I may change anytime.
From what I've read, there is only one way I know of:

```java
public class MyExtractor implements JsonDeserializer<Object> {
    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonElement elem, Type jtype,
            JsonDeserializationContext jdc) throws JsonParseException {
        // elem is an object
        JsonObject obj = elem.getAsJsonObject();
        String type = obj.get("type").getAsString();
        // Return a different kind of Object depending on the 'type' attr
        switch (type) {
        case "Boolean":
            Boolean bool = obj.get("value").getAsBoolean();
            return bool;
        case "String[]":
            JsonArray data = obj.get("value").getAsJsonArray();
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (JsonElement item : data) {
                list.add(item.getAsString());
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

And here I add code to associate each `type` to its proper class.
This will probably work as I want, but is there a better way?
This one ends up requiring quite a lot of template.

Also, the deserialized items are cast into `Object` so I don't
have access to their methods without reading their `getClass()` and
casting them back, and I can't benefit from [overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading).

Are there libraries with different approaches to the problem?

Comment: You can try taking a look at [dynamic code generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166135/dynamic-code-execution).

Comment: Can you change the json?

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO Yeah, I have access to the JavaScript which generates and uses this JSON. In theory I can do anything with it. In the JS, it's convenient to have all the objects in a single array, but this can change (merging multiple arrays is quite easy in JS). This would make deserialization easier I guess. For now the 'type' attribute is relevant in the unique-array, since there are 4 different "complex classes" with custom properties and behaviors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You can change the original json from:

```
[{
    "type": "Boolean",
    "value": false
}, {
    "type": "String[]",
    "value": ["one", "two", "three"]
}]
```

to

```
[false, ["one", "two", "three"]]
```

You can simply deserialize it as

```
String jsonString = ...
Object[] result = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Object[].class);
```

This work well for each standard type (`String`, `Boolean`, `Integer`...), for custom classes it will create a `Map`.

---

For example if the `jsonString` has content

```
["testString", false, {"name":"Davide", "surname":"Marino"}]
```

it will generate an Object array with:

- the `String` **testString** in first position
- the `Boolean` **false** in second position
- the `Map` with properties **name** (with value **Davide**) and **surname** (value **Marino**) in third position

---

If You don't need to handle existing java classes, but you have 3 4 custom classes you can use a polimorphic deserialization.

Basically you need to create a custom interface (or base class) and implement (or extend) it.
To see a more complete example see the accepted answer of

[Gson serialize a list of polymorphic objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588020/gson-serialize-a-list-of-polymorphic-objects)

Answer (score 1):

You can try jolt json transformer and then use one of the standard mappers (Jackson, gson ect)

Answer (score 0):

[pretius-jddl](https://github.com/Pretius/pretius-jddl) is capable of deserialization based on the existence or value of particular fields. The example in readme is almost exactly what you want.

In your case you'd have to create two rules that distinguish deserialization depending on the value of `type`:

```
DynamicObjectDeserializer deserializer = new DynamicObjectDeserializer();

deserializer.addRule(DeserializationRuleFactory.typeByFieldValue(1, 
    "type", "Boolean", Boolean.class));
deserializer.addRule(DeserializationRuleFactory.typeByFieldValue(1, 
    "type", "String[]", String[].class));
```

There's more information on this [blog post about jddl](https://pretius.com/json-deserialization-pretius-jddl/)